Difference between как/что/… угодно and как/что/… попало
This question recently caused me quite some headache. I sometimes have the feeling the two constructions are very similar in meaning just to perceive them as completely different, the next time I think about it.
So, I would be very glad if someone could explain me the difference in usage, tone, and meaning.
Examples:
For (1) and (2): I found (1) in the Internet, and created (2) by switching the two expressions I am asking about.

(1) «Многие думают, что он будет кушать всё, что попало»
(2) «Многие думают, что он будет кушать всё, что угодно»

For (3) and (4): I found (3) in the Internet and created (4) by switching expressions.

(3) «Я могу спать где угодно»
(4) «Я могу спать где попало»

For the two sample sets, I am not quite sure how they differ.
(Edit note: Added examples to make the question more specific)

Is there any specific example you have in mind? It would save us some guessing.

"whatever one wanted" vs "whatever one could"

@IgorG Good point. I edited and added two example sets. I hope this helps

@Swift: I also had this thought and generally I use it like this, I think. But then again, can‘t I also use «что угодно» as kind of a polite „whatever pleases you (because I don‘t care)“ which is basically the same as «что попало» which is „whatever“?

Как угодно means "as you wish, as you like" (literally, "as it pleases you").
Как попало means "haphazardly, any which way" (literally, "any way it befalls").
The former means that you can consciously choose any way to do something, or that the way something is done doesn't matter.
The latter describes how something comes out or ends up by pure chance.
Their meanings correspond to those of the English words "arbitrarily" and "randomly". As well as the English words, the Russian constructs are in certain contexts interchangeable, and in others can get confused easily.



Можно называть это опытом, мудростью, сменой жизненных приоритетов — как угодно. [Д. С. Филиппов. Билет в Катманду (2009) // «Волга», 2012]
You can call it experience, wisdom, change of priorities, any way you like.


Here it means you can call it any of these words, and you get to pick the name.


Вы думаете, что я могу обращаться с мячом как угодно, но это не так. [С. А. Самсонов. Ноги (2006)]
You think I can handle the ball any way I like, but it isn't so.


His party thinks he can control the ball any way he wants.



Сначала он вынимал и складывал аккуратно, потом принялся бросать как попало. [Александр Снегирев. Вера (2015)]
At first, he was taking them out and packing neatly, then he began to throw them together haphazardly.


He threw things any which way, without making any decisions about that.


В иных случаях дендриты ориентированы как попало, в других случаях — параллельно друг другу. [А. И. Китайгородский, Л. Д. Ландау. Физика для всех. Молекулы (1978)]
In some cases the dendrites are oriented any which way, in others, they are parallel to each other.


In the first case, the dendrites get oriented randomly.



Череп не пластилиновый, он не меняется как попало. [Станислав Дробышевский. Достающее звено. Книга 2. Люди (2017)]
The skull is not made out of Play-Doh, it can't change any which way.


In this negative construct you can replace it with как угодно. There are certain ways the skull can change. It's neither pure chance, nor can you change it however you like.


Гони прямо как попало, лишь бы покороче. [П. П. Улитин. Татарский бог и симфулятор (1991) // «Волга», 2012]
Drive straight, any which way, as long as it's a shorter route.


Here как угодно could have been used as well, because the driver chooses the way he drives. Как попало conveys the meaning that the driver should bother himself with picking a shorter route, and not sweat the small stuff.

Very good answer and exactly catches the concept I was struggling with. I add this comment for transparency to other readers: I edited my question while this answer here was being posted, hence it does not take into account the examples I added. But it contains exactly what I was looking for.
